# Gitlab Android Emulator in Docker : "Please ensure KVM is properly installed and usable."

Tags: android, docker, android-emulator, gitlab

**Background**

My Android project is hosted on Gitlab and I just want to run my UI tests using docker.
I have followed [this nice article](https://medium.com/@NickKaramoff/gitlab-ci-setup-for-an-android-app-3ba57b369b5f) to make my android UI tests run on emulator inside docker.I did everything exactly as written.

**The problem**

Build runs ok until the point where it has to launch the emulator , then I get the famous error (which I can't resolve) :

> $ ${ANDROID_HOME}/tools/emulator -avd test -no-window -no-audio
>   statvfs('/root/.android/avd/test.avd/snapshots/default_boot/ram.img') failed: No such file or directory
>   emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
>   Please ensure KVM is properly installed and usable.
>   CPU acceleration status: KVM requires a CPU that supports vmx or svm
>   More info on configuring VM acceleration on Linux:
>   https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration#vm-linux
>   General information on acceleration: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration.

**My setup**
I have tried Gitlab shared runners but also my own docker runner installed on my *MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2017, Two Thunderbolt 3 ports)* . I've configured my runner in *config.toml* file to run in privileged mode. Eventually the error was the same.

Can someone help me to solve my problem , or just point me to setup that works ? It should be a trivial thing but I cannot find a working solution anywhere.